# Orientation of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

In my differential geometry classed we defined that a manifold is Orientable if it contains a volume form, now I am trying to prove  that this equivalent to the existence of positive charts, that is a collection $\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}$ such that $\det \phi_i\circ\phi_j^{-1}(x)>0$, for every coordinate chart in this atlas.

I was able to do this $\Leftarrow$ using partitions of unity to define the volume form, but now I don't know how to do this $\Rightarrow$. Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  Given a volume form $\omega$, call a chart $(U,\phi)$ *correctly oriented* if $\omega = f\phi^\ast(dx_1\wedge....\wedge dx_n)$ for some positive function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Given a chart $(U,\phi)$, first show that you can modify $\phi$ to get a correctly oriented chart, then use these to make an atlas.

Comment: Alright yes that was very helpfulll, thank you ! @Jason DeVito

Comment: Something:  If you'd like, feel free to write the answer up yourself.